# How to select Dictionary value with most appearances

Tags: c#, linq

```
Dictionary<objectx,objecty> d.
```

I want to select object y with the most appearances in "d" using LINQ.

```
d.GroupBy(t => t.Value)
```

gave me result i cannot get values from.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
objecty maxOccurenceValue = d.GroupBy(kv => kv.Value)
                     .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                     .First().Key;
```

Note that your objects need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or implement [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx).

Comment: maxOccurenceValue.Group doesn't has Key or Value, it is collection itself

Comment: This works but one should be aware that the OrderByDescending means the whole sequence gets iterated an extra time than is necessary.

Comment: @eugeneK, a Group has a `Key` and represents a collection of values.

Comment: @eugeneK: Simplifed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're part way there. Now that you have the groups, you can use the `MaxBy` method from [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) to identify the value that has the highest count.

```
var highestFrequencyValue = d
    .GroupBy(t => t.Value)
    .MaxBy(g => g.Count())
    .Key;
```

The [implementation of MaxBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) gives some insight into how you might achieve this yourself (make sure to acknowledge the copyright/licensing).

Comment: Is there a way to do that without another library ?

Comment: Yes, you can code the method yourself. I would avoid the OrderBy approach as it will iterate your sequence more times than is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you really only care about which one happens most (and not which keys they had), just ignore that it's a `Dictionary` and act only on the list of `Value`.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"hi", 3},
    {"there", 3},
    {"you", 4},
    {"have", 5},
    {"a", 5},
    {"nice", 5},
    {"hat", 5},
    {"and", 6}, 
    {"shoes", 6},
};

var result = dict
    .Select(d => d.Value)
    .GroupBy(k => k)
    .OrderByDescending(k => k.Count())
    .First()
    .Key;

Console.WriteLine(result);

// 5
```

**EDIT**: I like not using the second transform. Thanks, @Tim. Changed mine and removed reference to stuff that's no longer in his post.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Order> orders=new List<Order>
            {new Order(){State="cali",ID=1},
            new Order(){State="cali",ID=2},
            new Order(){State="nali",ID=3},
            new Order(){State="pali",ID=4},
            new Order(){State="pali",ID=5},
            new Order(){State="cali",ID=3},
        };
        List<Order> gr=null;
        orders.GroupBy(g => g.State).ToList().ForEach(d=>
        {
            if(gr==null)
                gr = d.ToList<Order>();
            else if (gr.Count() < d.Count())
                gr = d.ToList<Order>();

        });
        return gr;
```

Yes you can do it with OrderBy , but I thinks OrderBy is heavy extended function if there are many elements in the List .I hope this will help.